# How to play mp4 video file from non-static directory in Flask

Tags: flask, video, mp4

I want to play mp4 video file in non-static directory.

I know this works if putting hello.mp4 under static directory (assuming static directory is created for Flask app)

```
<video width="800" height="450" controls>
   <source src="{{url_for('static', filename='hello.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But, I want to play hello.mp4 in non-static directory:

```
<video width="800" height="450" controls>
   <source src="/AnyDirectory/hello.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

How to do it in Flask?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out.

```
app.py

@app.route("/playvideourl/<filename>")
def playvideourl(filename): 
    return render_template('player-video.html', 
        movie_name='hello.mp4',
        movie_ext='mp4')

@app.route("/media_video/<filename>"):
def media_video(filename):
   # config_any_dir
   return send_from_directory(config_any_dir, filename, as_attachment=False)

play-video.html
<script type=text/javascript>
   const movie_name = {{ movie_name|tojson }};
</script>


  <video id="video" defaultMuted autoplay playsinline controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for('media_video', filename=movie_name) }}" type="video/{{movie_ext}}">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```